# How can act-on create a subdomain on our website

Tags: html, wordpress, subdomain

At my company, they have a Wordpress site. Disclaimer: I'm a new hire here.

They also use a third party service/website called "act-on". Within act-on, we can manage our campaigns, generate webforms that submit data back to act-on and generate anchor tags that link to resources that act-on hosts.

I want to be clear, we upload documents to act-on. Then, act-on gives us links that we can place on our website to these documents. When a user clicks the link on our website, they are taken to a subdomain of our website that they did not create, to view the resource.

When I talk about "act-on", I'm referring to this service:
https://www.act-on.com/

Example:
We live at websitename.com.
The anchor tag that act-on creates, links to solutions.websitename.com/acton/resourcename

We didn't create a page or subdomain "solutions.websitename.com" and don't have any pages that reflect that.

I need to know how this works because their google analytics doesn't seem to track page visits to this subdomain.

How has act-on created some subdomain on our website? I don't understand that process. How can act-on link to files that they host, but the url be a subdomain of our website.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to another company called reachlocal. They basically proxy all your web content, and in a lot of cases they even put up proxy phone numbers and record the calls audibly and transcript them. All this in addition to marketing campaigns such as analytics, PPC and alike.

A business essentially gives them this right when signing up and are told about it upfront.

It is all for the sake of keeping record in order on file of everything taking place, with web presence and "presented in a friendly interface and graphs. Which also allows employees to listen to recorded calls to "see how the employee does"

More than likely from my experience is they were given the keys for all web presence, including web, analytics, social sites and so on by the owner or project manager.

Unfortunately, by proxying all the websites they in turn get a lot of Google ranking, but it can be a valuable service for some.

**Bottom Line:** Someone at your job, signed up, gave them the go ahead to perform tasks such as proxy domain names and are in fact paying them.

Comment: So they are able to create subdomains for our website without us setting anything up or modifying htaccess? I guess I don't know anything about proxy domains. I thought if someone wanted to go to something.website.com, we always get the traffic. If it has to go to act-on's servers, I thought WE had to set this up in .htaccess at the least.

Comment: My understanding is in most cases the client needs to do nothing, at times, maybe just place a file in the root folder for instance, that is one method of verifying ownership for Analytics. Also it can be done through a Cname within your domain registrar. People in general are using proxy servers for many reasons, one being privacy and another being security, as they do not see the real files. In this case your brand gets marketed but they in turn get a lot of ranking by hosting the sites.